# How to filter out data from multiple states getting data from separate APIs in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, filter

I have had two states named `latestuploads` and `featuredspeakers` and I am getting data in both of these from separate APIs using Axios. Now I want that if I search the data from the `featuredapeakers` it should only filter out the `featuredspeakers` state and same like `latestuploads`. But I don't know want I am doing wrong. Pls look at my code and help me. thank you

```
class SearchPage extends Component {
state = {
  loading: false,
  featuredspeakers: [],
  latestuploads: [],
}}
componentDidMount() {
axios
  .all([
    axios.get(
      'https://staging.islamicmedia.com.au/wp-json/islamic-media/v1/featured/speakers',
    ),
    axios.get(
      'https://staging.islamicmedia.com.au/wp-json/islamic-media/v1/featured/latest-uploads',
    ),
  ])
  .then(responseArr => {

    this.setState({
      featuredspeakers: responseArr[0].data,
      latestuploads: responseArr[1].data,

      loading: !this.state.loading,
    });
  })}


searchFeatured = value => {
  const filterFeatured = (
    (this.state.latestuploads,this.state.featuredspeakers
  ).filter(item => {
    let featureLowercase = (item.name + " " + item.title).toLowerCase();
    let searchTermLowercase = value.toLowerCase();
    return featureLowercase.indexOf(searchTermLowercase) > -1;
  });
  this.setState({
    featuredspeakers: filterFeatured,
    latestuploads: filterFeatured
  });
};
```

and I am calling my searchFeatured function here

```
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={value => this.searchFeatured(value)}
    placeholder="SEARCH..."
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    style={styles.textInput}
  />
</View>;
```

Comment: you are filtering on both arrays

Comment: yes I want to filter both the arrays on one function which i have called in TextInput. I think i am doing something wrong. So pls tell me if if u get it. thanks

Comment: the filtering doesn't work?

Comment: filtering is working but only on latestuploads data not on other state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search on both arrays, combine the arrays into one array. I don't see the need to do the following, both  arrays will have the same values. To make your saerch work you'll need two arrays one for the data from the api and one for displaying the data, which will be used for filtering.

```
this.setState({
  featuredspeakers: filterFeatured,
  latestuploads: filterFeatured,
});
```

Your state will be like the following

```
state = {
    latestuploadsApiData: [],
    featuredspeakersApiData: [],
    latestuploads: [],
    featuredspeakers: []
}
```

Then in your axios call assign the arrays the same values

```
componentDidMount = () => {

  axios
    .all([
      axios.get(
        'https://staging.islamicmedia.com.au/wp-json/islamic-media/v1/featured/speakers'
      ),
      axios.get(
        'https://staging.islamicmedia.com.au/wp-json/islamic-media/v1/featured/latest-uploads'
      )
    ])
    .then(responseArr => {
      this.setState({
        featuredspeakers: responseArr[0].data,
        latestuploads: responseArr[1].data,
        latestuploadsApiData: responseArr[1].data,
        featuredspeakersApiData: responseArr[0].data,
        loading: !this.state.loading
      });
    });

}
```

In your search function combine the array and filter

```
searchFeatured = value => {
  const filterFeatured = [
    ...this.state.latestuploadsApiData,
    ...this.state.featuredspeakersApiData
  ].filter(item => {
    const searchString = `${item.name} ${item.title}`;

    return (
      searchString && searchString.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    );
  });

  // both arrays will have the same data
  this.setState({
    featuredspeakers: filterFeatured,
    latestuploads: filterFeatured
  });
};
```

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      name: 'React',
      latestuploadsApiData: [
        { title: 'React todo list', name: 'Cyril' },
        {
          title: 'Avoid Object Mutation for Better Performance',
          name: 'Michael'
        }
      ],
      featuredspeakersApiData: [
        { title: 'State of React', name: 'Junius' },
        { title: 'Javascript for Native', name: 'Peter' }
      ],
      latestuploads: [
        { title: 'React todo list', name: 'Cyril' },
        {
          title: 'Avoid Object Mutation for Better Performance',
          name: 'Michael'
        }
      ],
      featuredspeakers: [
        { title: 'State of React', name: 'Junius' },
        { title: 'Javascript for Native', name: 'Peter' }
      ]
    };
  }

  searchFeatured = value => {
    const filterFeatured = [
      ...this.state.latestuploadsApiData,
      ...this.state.featuredspeakersApiData
    ].filter(item => {
      const searchString = `${item.name} ${item.title}`;

      return (
        searchString && searchString.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
      );
    });

    this.setState({
      featuredspeakers: filterFeatured,
      latestuploads: filterFeatured
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>

        <input
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={e => {
            this.setState(
              {
                value: e.target.value
              },
              () => {
                this.searchFeatured(this.state.value);
              }
            );
          }}
          type='text'
        />

        <p>
          Featured speakers, will combine data from latestuploads once you start
          typing.
        </p>

        {this.state.featuredspeakers.map(item => (
          <p>{`${item.name} - ${item.title}`}</p>
        ))}

        <hr />

        <p>
          Latest uploads, will combine data from featuredspeakers once you start
          typing.
        </p>

        {this.state.latestuploads.map(item => (
          <p>{`${item.name} - ${item.title}`}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Comment: so close, but I want that when I search for some name of the speaker then it should only target the featuredspeaker state and latestuploads state data should remain same and same for latestuploads i am targetting the title from the array of latestuploads.